# For cleaning food and objects, power scrubber vs. electric rotary toothbrush?

Tags: friction

I'm asking about cleaning produce like potatoes and melons, NOT human organs here. [This handheld power scrubber](https://www.buzzfeed.com/nataliebrown/rubbermaid-reveal-power-scrubber-review)

[image]

looks like your average rotary toothbrush! Indubitably I know that a toothbrush's brush head can be far gentler than the power scrubber's. But what are other differences?

[image]

I whited out the brand name because I don't want to be accused of promoting a brand. I'm not.

Comment: I used a vibrating sander with a big scotchbrite sheet cut to fit instead of the sanding paper to clean bathroom tiles and joints... Worked very well and quick too.

Comment: Besides the mechanical, there might be differences in soaps or cleaning chemicals that can be used with the two methods, the possibility of using heat...  depends on what you're cleaning

Comment: @PeteW I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is not a smart plug-in, I agree with what you said yourself.

The toothbrush must be gentle, able to reach in between multi-faceted complex geometry of our teeth and gums. They try to maintain the teeth' health by mostly dislodging the germs from their particular strata, relative to their altitude above the gum line. Some try to dislodge the tartar by ultrasonic vibrations.

Grout brushes or tile cleaning tools come in a wide variety of scales and configurations. Floor-sweeping machines are industrial tools designed for intense pressure and grinding action. Some work connected to high-pressure water pumps spraying the work area. some clean and wax; some are as big as a forklift and have a seat and controls for the operators.